# Django model is truncating a decimal place when passed to the view when DecimalField is set

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

Django Model:

```
class TwoDecimal(models.Model):
   two_decimal = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10)
```

View:

```
def two_decimal(request):
    test = TwoDecimal(
        two_decimal = 30.00
    )
    test.save()
    return render(
        request,
        "test-template.html",
        {"test": test}
    )
```

Template:

```
{{ test.two_decimal }}  #==> Displays as 30.0 instead of 30.00 (Despite it being a two decimal field.)
```

This displays properly if it is a query from already saved data.

Why is django truncating this decimal place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass it a decimal, right now you pass it a `float`. The fact that it is then saved in a `DecimalField` does *not* make the attribute a `Decimal`. If you would later retrieve it, then it indeed will be retrieved as a decimal.

```
from decimal import Decimal

def two_decimal(request):
    test = TwoDecimal(
        two_decimal = Decimal('30.00')
    )
    test.save()
    return render(
        request,
        'test-template.html',
        {'test': test}
    )
```

Note that it is important to pass the value as a *string* to the `Decimal` constructor. Otherwise it might introduce small rounding errors, and furthermore it does no longer contain information about the number of digits.